# Pacifica heater core hose reconnect

Tags: heater

I have 2005 Chrysler Pacifica touring edition. A mechanic connected the two hoses together that should be connected to the heater core, because we had a water leak and he thought it would fix it. Well it didn't and the mechanic cannot be located. I'm trying to figure out which hose goes to the top and which goes to the bottom of the heater core?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't want to add this as an answer, but for my ancient '85 Ford E150, there is no flow direction requirement. I can't say if that's true of other vehicles.

Comment: Agree, it shouldn't matter. The coolant just needs to flow through for it to heat the core.

Comment: Ok great,I wasn't sure if it would mess anything up or not. Well that makes it much easier then, thanks guys.

Comment: After you verify a solution, please come back and post it as an answer, then mark that as the answer for the question.

Comment: Yep everything seems to be working good now, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

**OP Resolved the Issue**

flow direction was not an issue.

OP reconnected hoses and stated the issue is now closed.